# Since when is 2 greater 15(simple if statement going awry)

Tags: jquery, input, if-statement

This is a snippet of a larger website I working on. All I am trying to do is some input validation. If the number they insert in a text box is greater then the max value(which is a attribute of the input box) display a tipsy error and grey out button etc. Well i can not figure out what is happening here.

```
>if(value>max)

>value:1 max:15 = No error
>
>value:2 max:15 = Error

>..... =Error
>
>value:10 max 15 = No error
```

So i took my code out of the website and put it in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/V9xfj/

and it does it in there as well. Type in a 2 and you will get an error.

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var max = parseFloat($(this).attr('max'));
var input = parseFloat($(this).val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V9xfj/1/

Answer (score 9):

2 is greater than 15 if they're strings or any other alpha sort

Comment: use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert from a string to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the value of the input to an integer.  try using the ParseInt method

```
var input = ParseInt($(this).val());
```

Comment: Makes sense but for some reason ParseInt didn't work but parseFloat did that xbrady posted did. Not sure why. Correction: Dose work. Thank you.(forgot to cap the Int part)